# замена стиля css с добавлением в cookies

Tags: javascript, css

Довольно долго искал информацию, но так и не нашёл.
Кратко: Есть три css файла. С помощью кнопки мы будем менять файл css. Важно что-бы стиль сохранился и после повторного открытия сайта и/или перезапуска браузера.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужен либо хостинг, чтобы файлы были на нём и ты их сосал через:

```js
let link = 'http://hosting/1.css';
$('body').append(`<link id="myStyle" rel="stylesheet" href="${link}">`);
```

Либо нужно создавать экстет(расширение хром), который уже будет содержать три этих файла, и хоть через [execute](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), хоть через  другую магию меняешь как надо

Удалять так(через `c.t.execute` можно этот код прокинуть):

```js
$('#myStyle').remove();
```

```js
// on change:
localStorage.styleState = 1; // Will be string

// on load:
if(localStorage.styleState === '1'){
    // inject 1.css
}
```

Comment: Вадим, допустим на ютубе с/без авторизации в правой верхней менюшке можно заменить стиль css (заменить белую тему на тёмную). Я вот что-то вроде этого хочу сделать) Хостинг есть, как и поддержка php.

Comment: Я до сих пор не понимаю, твой ли это сайт или нет. Для твоего случая подойдет [это](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), я думаю (вместо стилей, colors файл меняешь). Ютюб там дров наломал, самая худшая реализация, как по мне с точки зрения всего